# Confusion while limiting the scope of selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to limit the scope of my WebDriver but I am not getting the desired result. Can someone help me what is happening here ?

1.If I use the below code the output is 21:

```
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='innings_1']"));      

System.out.println(table.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='cb-col cb-col-100 cb-scrd-itms']")).size());
```

2.Whereas if use the below code output is 13:

```
System.out.println(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='innings_1'] //div[@class='cb-col cb-col-100 cb-scrd-itms']")).size());
```

I am expecting the 1st block of code should also give output as 13 because I am limiting the scope of the webdriver

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to add `.` before the xpath while limiting the score as shown below.

```
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='innings_1']"));      

System.out.println(table.findElements(By.xpath(".//div[@class='cb-col cb-col-100 cb-scrd-itms']")).size());
```

If you don't specify the `.` then findElement will try to execute the xpath on the whole DOM rather on the current node. So we can restrict the xpath to work on the current node by adding `.` at the starting of xpath.